# Fishpig Wordpress Post redirect

Tags: redirect, wordpress

A store uses Fishpig Wordpress module for blog functionality in Magento. I want to redirect one post url to another one. How can I achieve using standard Magento url redirection rule on admin->Catalog->Url Redirections.

```
request url: /blog/some-category/post-slug
target url: /blog/another-category/post-slug
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento rewrites searches for the extension `.html` for rewrites(if configured this way in the backend of coarse)

Just add it in your .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /blog/some-category/post-slug /blog/another-category/post-slug [QSA,R=301,L]`